# Understanding reflection classes

Tags: php

I am trying to understand how reflection classes work, I am unable to find a good explanation of one and examples, but also a little help with my own issue!

So, first off my issue:

When making a new reflectionClass I cannot seem to get it to work and use the class.

Here is my code:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("Feature\\CollectionTesting\\CollectionTest");
```

And from what I read from the documentation you are meant to pass it a class name (but mines not in the same directory or in the same file).

This is obviously wrong as it throws me an error:

```
Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Feature\CollectionTesting\CollectionTest does not exist in (my current file)
```

With this I was also told I would need to load the classes into the file to be able to use them so I have done like so:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($finalPath) {
                include $finalPath;
            });
```

Where `$finalPath` is the path to the file itself. For example it would be something like:

```
Feature\\CollectionTesting\\CollectionTest.class.php
```

Is someone able to explain to me how they work and provide examples, plus help me with my issue or help me understand what the issue is so I can get this working?

Comment: did you have imported that namespace? (using `use` in the top of the file) Also, you can use `CollectionTest::class` to get the full path of a class (with their namespace)

Comment: I will give this a try and let you know !

Comment: @Chemaclass `use` won't actually load the file either. You just need to ensure the actual file that includes the code is loaded before you try to reflect on it. You can use an autoloader to do that, or you use a good old `require_once` at the top of your file.

Comment: the issue is I won't know beforehand the files I need to use

Comment: Then use an autoloader. Is your question how to build an autoloader?

Comment: Hmm, not really. Sorry I am bad at explanations. So what I want to be able to achieve: read a file and use a function that will return a large array of data (from my tests). But the PHP script I am making will not be in a class, so won't be instantiated

Comment: Don't you use composer?

Comment: yes, but I don't want to use it for this scenarios